# impossible to draw a different texture on my cubes on XNA

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, textures, draw

I'm having some problem to draw textures with class "**DrawUserIndexPrimitive**" on Xna.

I can draw my cubes / models without problem. But I want to draw **different textures on my cubes**.
I loop on each "ID" of a different texture applied to my different cube. But it does not work. I apply every time buffer and vertexPosition with IndexBuffer different from my class "GraphicData."

the final texture to be applied **is the same on all my cubes**

thank you

Here is my code for function "Draw"

```
public void drawWorld(GameTime gameTime) 
    { 
        if (needToDraw) 
        { 
            int index = 0; 
            foreach (GraphicData data in graphicData) 
            { 

                effet.LightingEnabled = false; 
                effet.VertexColorEnabled = false; 
                effet.TextureEnabled = true; 
                effet.FogEnabled = false; 
                effet.FogStart = arcadia.camera.NearPlane; 
                effet.FogEnd = arcadia.camera.FarPlane; 
                effet.FogColor = new Vector3(1, 1, 1); 
                effet.View = arcadia.camera.View; 
                effet.Projection = arcadia.camera.Projection; 
                effet.Texture = data.Texture2D;
                //I hardcoded with a condition for check that the texture changes well in my loop
                /*
                if (index == 0) 
                { 
                    effet.Texture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Models\\Ground\\Land\\ground_land_text1"); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    effet.Texture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Models\\Ground\\Land\\ground_land_text2"); 
                } 
                */
                foreach (EffectPass pass in effet.CurrentTechnique.Passes) 
                { 
                    pass.Apply(); 
                    //Initialize et envoie à la carte graphique le buffer et les vertices 
                    if (data.vertexBuffer != null && data.indexBuffer != null) 
                    { 
                        Game.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(data.vertexBuffer); 
                        Game.GraphicsDevice.Indices = data.indexBuffer; 
                        Game.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, data.vertexPosition, 0, data.vertexPosition.Length, data.indices, 0, data.indices.Length / 3); 
                    } 

                } 
                index++; 
            } 
        } 


    }
```

Comment: I would probably load the textures outside of the draw loop for a start, may benefit performance a bit as the load call has to check if loaded and then assign to the effect Texture.

Comment: Yes I do it exactly! But to "debug" and check that the texture changes well in my loop, I hardcoded with a condition to better show and explain my problem. I have edited my code for best explain

Comment: Duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51507/how-to-draw-different-textures-on-my-cubes-drawuserindexprimitive-with-xna

Comment: Yes I'm sorry .. Should I close my post?

Comment: I wrote my second post on "Game Dev" afterwards because after thought, I think it's a question about the game on Xna develloppement.